# Fabric Crashlytics: Some devices have missing stacktrace

Tags: google-fabric

Some devices missing NDK Crash Report stacktrace but there is stack trace in logcat.

Devices: HTC Sensation XE - Android version 
Samsung Galaxy S6 SM-G920F - Android version  6.0.1
Other tested devices work good(lenovo TAB 2 A10-70L).

We use 
crashlytics version 2.6.8
crashlytics-core 2.3.17
crashlytics-ndk 1.1.5

logcat after crash:

```
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zerofltexx/zeroflte:6.0.1/MMB29K/G920FXXU5DQA7:user/release-keys'
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): Revision: '11'
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): ABI: 'arm'
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): pid: 24441, tid: 24441, name: lquantum.iceage  >>> com.socialquantum.iceage <<<
07-04 18:07:42.601: A/DEBUG(3057): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 119672840 (?), fault addr 0x1
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057): Abort message: 'PRODUCTION: Adjust is running in Production mode. Use this setting only for the build that you want to publish. Set the environment to sandbox if you want to test your app!'
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     r0 00000001  r1 df17f360  r2 0000001e  r3 2a1ed63c
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     r4 ffcf4d98  r5 ffcf4f80  r6 d73fdd18  r7 ffcf4e68
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     r8 d73fdd00  r9 ffcf4e84  sl d73fdd14  fp ffcf51bc
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     ip f4c42000  sp ffcf4d98  lr de890aff  pc de1a5646  cpsr 00010030
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057): backtrace:
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #00 pc 00c8e646  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #01 pc 01379afd  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #02 pc 013797c7  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #03 pc 013c7131  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #04 pc 013b0a3f  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #05 pc 0078ac5b  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #06 pc 00783795  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/lib/arm/libaicefarmint.so (Java_com_socialquantum_acountry_GameMain_nativeMotionSend+288)
07-04 18:07:42.651: A/DEBUG(3057):     #07 pc 00c44c5f  /data/app/com.socialquantum.iceage-1/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x984000)
07-04 18:07:43.151: A/DEBUG(3057): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
07-04 18:07:43.151: E/DEBUG(3057): AM write failed: Broken pipe'
```

---

logcat after relaunch game:

```
07-04 18:07:53.781: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Initializing libcrashlytics version 1.1.5
07-04 18:07:53.781: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Attempting to load unwinder...
07-04 18:07:53.791: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Done; using libunwind
07-04 18:07:53.791: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Attempting to register signal handler...
07-04 18:07:53.791: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Signal handler registered.
07-04 18:07:53.791: D/libcrashlytics(24695): Initializing native crash handling successful.
07-04 18:07:53.791: I/CrashlyticsCore(24695): Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.17.dev
07-04 18:07:54.521: W/System.err(24695): remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.socialquantum.iceage/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/log-files/crashlytics-userlog-595BAE350254-0001-5F79-9BA6530D4A98.temp
07-04 18:07:57.141: I/CrashlyticsCore(24695): Crashlytics report upload complete: 595BAE350254-0001-5F79-9BA6530D4A98
```

why there is empty stacktrace?

[image: [1]]